# Msg 2750 specified column precision error SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I try to add a FacilitySt table, I get an error code that I have never seen before and I have no idea why it occurs here. SQL query creating a table:

```
CREATE TABLE FacilitySt
(
    IdFacility int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    DBA_Name nvarchar(200) NOT NULL,
    AKA_Name nvarchar(200) NOT NULL,
    License int NOT NULL,
    FacilityType nvarchar(200) NOT NULL,
    Risk nvarchar(200) NOT NULL,
    InspectionType nvarchar(200) NOT NULL,
    Address nvarchar(200) NOT NULL,
    Latitude float(200) NOT NULL,
    Longitude float(200) NOT NULL,
    Location geography NOT NULL
)
GO
```

Error message:

> Msg 2750, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Column or parameter #9: Specified column precision 200 is greater than the maximum precision of 53.

SQL operating environment is SQL Server.

Comment: The error is *literally* telling you the problem here. What about the error don't you understand bans we can try to elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you intend with `float(200)`, but this works:

```
CREATE TABLE FacilitySt(
    IdFacility int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    DBA_Name nvarchar(200) NOT NULL,
    AKA_Name nvarchar(200) NOT NULL,
    License int NOT NULL,
    FacilityType nvarchar(200) NOT NULL,
    Risk nvarchar(200) NOT NULL,
    InspectionType nvarchar(200) NOT NULL,
    Address nvarchar(200) NOT NULL,
    Latitude float NOT NULL,
    Longitude float NOT NULL,
    Location geography NOT NULL
)
```

If you want to check the ranges, you can use a `check` constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE FacilitySt(
    IdFacility int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    DBA_Name nvarchar(200) NOT NULL,
    AKA_Name nvarchar(200) NOT NULL,
    License int NOT NULL,
    FacilityType nvarchar(200) NOT NULL,
    Risk nvarchar(200) NOT NULL,
    InspectionType nvarchar(200) NOT NULL,
    Address nvarchar(200) NOT NULL,
    Latitude float NOT NULL,
    Longitude float NOT NULL,
    Location geography NOT NULL,
     check (latitude between -180 and 180 and longitude between -180 and 180)
)
```

Often, latitudes and longitudes are stored as decimal/numeric values with some number of decimal points.  In many cases, `decimal(10, 7)` is sufficient.

I say this because equality may not work as expected with floating point values.

Comment: Do you know how for the second value in decimal I would like to use more than 10 for example: decimal(10,20) what I would have to use ?

Comment: @ffallerrol: the definition of `decimal(p,s)` is: `p` is the **total** number of digits (before **and** after the decimal point), whereas `s` is the number of digits **after** the decimal point. So a `decimal(10,20)` doesn't make any sense at all - 10 digits total, 20 of which after the decimal point......